# Spree: Move to next stage depending on answer on checkout flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

i'm trying to use Spree for a Food Ordering system for a restaurant.

I've modified the Checkout flow, so the first step is to choose between Home Delivery or Shop Eating.

If user selects "Delivery", it will jump to address page.
If user selects "Shop Eating", it will skip address page.

I suppose I need to create a new boolean column to some Spree table for this (what table?), and,
how do I say "If user checks Shop Eating, skip the Address page" ???

Thanks!

**My checkout flow**

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
checkout_flow do
  go_to_state :address
  go_to_state :payment, if: ->(order) {
    order.update_totals
    order.payment_required?
  }
  go_to_state :confirm, if: ->(order) { order.confirmation_required? }
  go_to_state :complete
  remove_transition :from => :delivery, :to => :confirm
end
  insert_checkout_step :seleccionar_delivery, :before => :address
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would put 'eating' on Spree::Order, simply, `go_to_state :address, unless: :eating?` If you want that step to be skipped.

If you you want to go to address OR seleccionar_delivery depending on the value of eating:

```
go_to_state :address, unless: :eating?
go_to_state :seleccionar_delivery, if: :eating?
go_to_state :payment
```

... Checkout continues as normal. You dont need to use the insert_checkout_step helper if you're already overriding the checkout flow, just add another go_to_state. I would also suggest another name for selccionar_delivery. But this should solve your issue.

Just as a sidenote, Spree might seem a tad over developed for simply one restaurant.